# How to setup hibernate datasouce in Java SE

Tags: java, hibernate, datasource, jndi

I read almost all thread about How configure hibernate datasource but I can't find help. I mean in `hibernate.cfg.xml` element `<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource"> ? </property>` i know i have to set up with jndi. i try to google it but all articles are based on developing with jbossas, ejb, tomcat, weblogic and their jndi. But i need jndi of java SE. Correct me please if i am wrong.

I am new to Hibernate so I am using NetBeans, SE project with Hibernate 3.2.5 jars. (I am studying Hibernate from book Beginning Hibernate 2nd edition, apress and source code derive on the book...)

My `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
  <hibernate-configuration>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
      com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
      jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/asd
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>

    <!-- nastaveni dialektu -->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">
      org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
    </property>

    <!-- jndi nastaveni -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">
      java:hibernate/SessionFactory
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="cache.provider_class">
      org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.jndi.class">javax.naming.InitialContext</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And I have only one class `FirstHibernate`:

```
package firsthibernate;

import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

public class FirstHibernate {

    private static SessionFactory session = null;
    private static Session s = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            session = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            s = session.openSession();

            s.beginTransaction();
            // List l = s.createQuery("from query").list();
            s.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            if (s.getTransaction() != null) {
                //s.getTransaction().rollback();
            }
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        } finally {
            s.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I obtain this message:

```
SEVERE: Could not obtain initial context javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: javax.naming.InitialContext [Root exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.naming.InitialContext cannot be cast to javax.naming.spi.InitialContextFactory]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that complex setup for SE.
Hope this link helps

1. [Hibernate Sample App](http://www.vaannila.com/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-annotations-1.html)
2. [Check Hibernate Quick Start](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/hibernate-tutorials/)

Comment: thank you :) i changed element <session-factory name="java:hibernate/SessionFactory"> to <session-factory> and it working because i try to persist test class to db.

Answer (score 0):

From what i perceive you are configuring hibernate in a non managed environment  . In Non managed environment hibernate handles the connections via simple connection pools .Its not possible to have a data source configured in the non managed mode . You can have a look at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-demarcation-nonmanaged for further details .